# Android hover cursor

Tags: android, android-source

I need to be able to change the cursor icon in Android when hovering over an element.
I'm already getting an event when hovering, but now I can't figure out how to change the cursor icon based on that.

I'm building from source, which means I'm able to change stuff in the framework.

From my research I've found that the pointer has several "states":

(From [/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml))

```
<!-- Pointer styles -->
<style name="Pointer">
    <item name="android:pointerIconArrow">@android:drawable/pointer_arrow_icon</item>
    <item name="android:pointerIconSpotHover">@android:drawable/pointer_spot_hover_icon</item>
    <item name="android:pointerIconSpotTouch">@android:drawable/pointer_spot_touch_icon</item>
    <item name="android:pointerIconSpotAnchor">@android:drawable/pointer_spot_anchor_icon</item>
</style>
```

How can I change the icon to these states?

Or is it in [/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/PointerIcon.java](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/PointerIcon.java) I need to make a change?

Comment: I don't think there is any public API. This is a built-in behavior...

Comment: But when is the pointerIconSpotHover used then?

Comment: When you're using a stylus